# Local static object and exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

How should I work with exceptions throwed from constructors of local static objects? For example I have following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {throw runtime_error("Ooops");}
};

void foo()
{
    static A a = A();
    cout << "Continue" << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
    foo(); // Prints continue
    return 0;
}
```

As I understand, in the case of second calling `foo` method, object `a` is treated as fully constructed object, and constructor is not called. (More over, it seems like destructor of `a` due first exception throwing is not called)

Comment: No, your understanding is not correct. You could have tried this out yourself [trivially](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0zqV3BglWpVZSgRM).

Comment: How do you expect `a` to be fully constructed if you threw an exception and terminated the execution of the constructor (which didn't finish constructing the object)?

Comment: `static A a = A();` Why did you do this? Why copy-initialise?

Comment: @KerrekSB, I am using msvc 2015, and My program prints continue (in debugger mode). otherwise it fails

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, I cannot understand behaviour of program in such case

Comment: Are you compiling with exceptions disabled?

Comment: @KerrekSB, I am using /EHsc option.

Comment: @KerrekSB: To be fair, the OP is saying they are (correctly) working out what VS is doing, which is (correctly) counter to their expectations. A little awkward wording in the final paragraph but I think the OP is entirely correct, and there's nothing to trivially try out.

Comment: @LmTinyToon, i'm using VS2015 and in both (attached and deattached dubuger) cases program fill fail with uncaught exception. If debugger is attached then the usual "unhandled exception" dialog appears. And it never gets to "Continue" unless you explicitly allow program to continue.

Comment: @VTT, ohh , you are right. It is my mistake, I used continue in the case of second exception throwing.

Comment: @LmTinyToon: So this isn't the actual program you ran? Please do not waste our time like this :(

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, I just used debugger wrongly, I thought continue option contunes exception unwinding

Comment: @LmTinyToon: You also claimed that the program _"// Prints continue"_. It does not.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, that's true, in the case of pressing continue, my program continues execution and prints continue

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: Fair enough, though it would be trivial to try out a few other compilers! :-) (Especially after perhaps consulting your textbook to double-check your understanding.)

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Okay; sounds like a strange thing for a debugger to do then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If that's true, then that is a compiler bug.**

*(However, [VTT claims that this code produces the expected result with Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609186/local-static-object-and-exception/43609303#comment74267311_43609300), so I recommend double-checking your results.)*

Here's the standard-mandated behaviour:

> `[C++14: 6.7/4]:` The zero-initialization (8.5) of all block-scope variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is performed before any other initialization takes place. Constant initialization (3.6.2) of a block-scope entity with static storage duration, if applicable, is performed before its block is first entered. An implementation is permitted to perform early initialization of other block-scope variables with static or
>   thread storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is permitted to statically initialize a variable with static or thread storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2). Otherwise such a variable is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization. **If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration.** If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization. If control re-enters the declaration recursively while the variable is being initialized, the behavior is undefined. *[..]*

[GCC 6.3.0 correctly attempts to reconstruct the `A`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b0827340e3da9f8) (and thus throws again).

---

> More over, it seems like destructor of a due first exception throwing is not called

No, it won't be. You can't destroy an object that was never successfully created in the first place.

> `[C++14: 15.2/2]:` An object of any storage duration whose initialization or destruction is terminated by an exception will have destructors executed for all of its fully constructed subobjects (excluding the variant members of a union-like class), that is, for subobjects for which the principal constructor (12.6.2) has completed execution and the destructor has not yet begun execution. Similarly, **if the non-delegating constructor for an object has completed execution and a delegating constructor for that object exits with an exception, the object’s destructor will be invoked.** If the object was allocated in a *new-expression*, the matching deallocation function (3.7.4.2, 5.3.4, 12.5), if any, is called to free the storage occupied by the object.

---

By the way, this doesn't fix the problem, but you should just write:

```
static A a;
```

The copy-initialisation from a temporary is pointless.

Comment: 6.7/4 "If the initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration."

Comment: @BoundaryImposition,  behaviour of program in attached/dettached debugger differs (I mean msvc 2015). In the case of dettached debugger programs fails

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Your compiler is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Each instance of static local variable also implicitly creates a global Boolean variable that will be set to true after static variable is constructed. If constructor throws than the next time method is called there will be another attempt to construct a static variable.

Comment: hmm, it looks like he didn't even run his code (and it actually has an uncaught exception), see [working example](http://ideone.com/4HZSTO) and it works fine in VS2015 too

Comment: Interesting! I don't have VS2015 to confirm.